# TKinter columnconfigure resize option not working

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, grid, tkinter-entry

This is my code to resize a tkinter entry, but it doesnt work. Can someone please help me figure it out? It doesn't resize even though I use columnconfigure and sticky. My code is below

```
self.ScriptEntry = tk.Entry(self,textvariable=self.FileText) 
self.ScriptEntry.grid(column=2,row=0, columnspan=2, sticky = W+E) 
self.ScriptEntry.columnconfigure(2, weight = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

`columnconfigure` and `rowconfigure` must be called on the widget that contains the entry. In this case that would be `self.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)`.

Comment: I tried this, but it still doesn't show any change. Is there anything else I should be doing?

Comment: @NupurDave: if that's what you tried, you need to give us a proper [mcve]. Otherwise there's just not enough information in your question.